# Dump Data into Hadoop with realtime encryption and Hierarchical Masking of some columns of data

Tags: hadoop, encryption, hdfs

Say i have a dataset/table(Banking sector) which has the following details.

```
Name  |  Mob.no |  AccountNo  |  Address |  SSN  | Salary....... |and so on.
john  |  123456 |   987654321 |  abx 123 | 1122  | 28000
```

I have to dump this into Hadoop.

But while dumping i want the `AccountNo` and `SSN` columns to be encrypted,

while its getting stored in HDFS.

This is the first part.

Now when i am retriving the results,

1. First decryption should happen.
2. After that i want to mask some of the columns.

Say. There are two Persons(CEO, Project Manager) Viewing the results of  `john`.

Then, CEO should be able to see all the details(columns) after decryption.

For Project Manager , the column `AccountNo` and `Salary` Should be Masked

For example:

```
Name  |  Mob.no |  AccountNo  |  Address |  SSN  | Salary....... |and so on.
john  |  123456 |   9876xxxxx |  abx 123 | 1122  | xxxxx
```

IS there any way to achieve this in Hadoop.

1. Encrypting column's of data while Dumping into HDFS.
2. Masking columns based on Hierarchy .

Any Leads would be appreciated,Since i am new to hadoop

Comment: is this what you are lookin for https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/cdh_sg_hdfs_encryption.html

Comment: @siddharthajain I guess i would have to go through the documentation first, Still its only about encryption, anything about masking?

Comment: Are you are planning to develop some sort of program which will read data from hdfs and display it to end user

Comment: @siddharthajain YES, Kind of, but as for now, just researching

Comment: yes, then it is possible to do masking. It will work like any conventional program where you can take some password key from user and can display result according to it. Now on which stage you will implement this key logic depends on your dataset if it is too large then it would be better to use it in setup method of mapper class otherwise reducer will also work.